# Imported a JSON file, trying to filter out specific keys/values and export them to excel. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, excel, import, export

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("C:/Users/name/Documents/metadata.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data['shots'])

for x in data['shots']['current_samples']['current']:
    print([x])

#df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#df = pd.json_normalize(data["shots"])

#df.to_excel('C:/Users/name/Documents/metadata.xlsx')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\JsontoExcel\main.py", line 9, in 
for x in data['shots']['current_samples']['current']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Which line fails? Please include the traceback. And check types. Either `data`,  `data['shots']` or `data['shots'][lcurrent_samples']` is a list.

Comment: Those types are as follows: data is a mix of string and ints, shots is an int, current samples is an int

Comment: Wait, what does "shots is an int" mean? You treat `data['shots']` as a dictionary, not an int. You could do `print(f"{type(data)}")` then on the next line `print(f"{type(data['shots'])}")` then another line with  `print(f"{type(data['shots']['current_samples'])}")`. That would show the types.

Comment: Right you are. Ok so this is a dictionary. 'shots' is a key that has a key called 'current_samples', which itself leads to a value. So key, key, value -> shots, current_samples, int type. I'm still brand new with python so sorry this is disorganized